# Thunderbird/Firefox Centralized Management. Move prefs.js to another location

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

I'd like to have centralized management of Thunderbird/Firefox profiles of all  users in my company. They already have installed and manually configured Thunderbird profiles on their PCs(running Windows in AD domain).
For instance, I need to make changes on all these computers regarding e-mail identities("Mail From" name, etc.) and possibly some minor changes in the future.

I'd like to have all prefs.js kept in one place. Then I'd be able to configure them just as plain text files doing whatever needed.
Therefore question is: How to specify Thunderbird to look for prefs.js in  another location?

I mean it'd be perfect to have settings for all users in one directory, like this:

```
\file-server\thunderbird\user1.prefs.js
\file-server\thunderbird\user2.prefs.js
```

...
etc.

P.S. I've already tried:

1. To make symbolic link of prefs.js file (with mklink command) to let's say "C:\test.js".
   And it did not work as well. (Thunderbird just replaces this symbolic link with new dummy prefs.js). I suppose it would work on Linux, but I've done this experiment on Windows and it did not make the trick).
2. To use general.config.filename directive to specify copy of prefs.js file as config file. However it complains "Failed to read the configuration file" (It seems Thunderbird accepts just config file in the same directory, specifying the full path is not acceptable)

Comment: Can you maybe use a synching programme which overwrites the local files with the ones on the server?

Comment: Have you checked that *general.config.filename* has the right encoding (should be **UTF-8** and not **ANSI**...)?

Answer (score 1):

You can (centrally) prepare and then **distribute** profiles and settings, but no you cannot centrally store parts of a profile and share out those profile parts to multiple people.  Profile files are under no circumstances to be shared.

See [enterprise references](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird/Enterprise) for information about deployment and a forum where you can ask questions